# How to echo a variable into a div in php?

Tags: php, html, echo

Im trying to echo a variable into an already existing DIV within a table.

EG:

```
<table>
  <tr> 
      <td class="error"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<?php 

 echo "<td class='error'>".$variable."</td>";
?>
```

Note: the error td tag is already style and positioned within a table.
The method above causes a lone td tag to be created and added to the top of
the page.

I realise it's probably best to echo php in HTML rather than vice versa but
I need echo HTML in this instance.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution, if I am understanding correctly:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="error"><?php echo $variable; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You have to `echo` in-place.

Comment: thanks for answering, that will of course output the variable but it should only be output under a certain condition and the code that decides that is on another page